# How to avoid making permanent replacements in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

Not sure if this is the correct way to ask the question. See sample code below. The downside to this code is I cant run the cell more than once without having to download the original dataset again. Is there anyway around this where I don't have to set it equal to a new DataFrame?

```
df.source = df['source'].str.split(',').str[1]
```

Comment: No, I don't think it's possible

Comment: 1. why dont you just set it to a new column then? 2. it would be helpfull if you tell us more of want you want to achieve

Comment: Or work on a copy of your original dataset, so that you don't have to read/download it again, just put `df = df_original.copy()` at the beginning of your script, assuming you have your original DataFrame as `df_original`

Comment: I guess creating a new column would allow me to run the cell as many times as I want. In that case I wouldn't be able to drop the original column.

Comment: why dont you want to create a `copy`?

Answer (score 0):

If you just run `df['source'].str.split(',').str[1]`, it will print out the result without replacing the original data frame or requiring you to set it equal to a new one.

As mentioned in the comments, you can create a new column instead:

```
df['source2'] = df['source'].str.split(',').str[1]
```

Comment: Yes, and I guess I'm just asking this because of an inconvenience for my specific situation. I want to change the dataframe column, but say I wanted to go back and specify str[2] instead of str[1]. I would no longer be able to do this without having to redownload the dataset.

Comment: In that case, I would recommend creating a new data frame and keeping the original unmodified. Is the data too large to fit two copies in memory?

Answer (score 0):

Consider creating a [deep](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html) copy of the dataframe and overwrite whatever you want as any modification made to the copied dataframe won't be reflected in your original one.

```
df1 = df.copy()
```